# Múltiples imágenes de fondo con background{}

Tags: css

Estoy intentando poner múltiples fondos con una sola declaración de CSS, así:

```
background{dodgerblue url(imatges/flag1.png), url(imatges/flag2.png), url(imatges/fondo.gif)}
```

Sin embargo, así no aparece nada, ni siquiera el color de fondo.

***Busco concentrarlo***, ya que las imágenes de fondo también tienen varios atributos, y evitar tenerlos desperdigados en `background-size`, `background-repeat`, `background position` y `background-attachment`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me temo que si quieres poner más de una imagen lo tendrás que hacer a través de la propiedad `background-image`.

Si sólo vas a utilizar una imagen sí que puedes indicarla dentro de la propiedad `background`:

```css
#fondo{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  background: dodgerblue url("https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_tree.gif");
}

#fondo2{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_tree.gif"), url("https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif");
}
```

```html
<div id="fondo"></div>

<div id="fondo2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mira creo que este es buen ejemplo para lo que preguntas...

```
<ol>
    <li>no-repeat
        <div class="one">&nbsp;</div>
    </li>
    <li>repeat
        <div class="two">&nbsp;</div>
    </li>
    <li>repeat-x
        <div class="three">&nbsp;</div>
    </li>
    <li>repeat-y
        <div class="four">&nbsp;</div>
    </li>
    <li>repeat-x, repeat-y (multiple images)
        <div class="five">&nbsp;</div>
    </li>
```

Este es el css:

```
li {margin-bottom: 12px;}
div {
    background-image: url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/12005/starsolid.gif);
    width: 144px;
    height: 84px;
}

/* background repeat CSS */
.one {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.two {
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
.three {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.four {
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

/* Multiple images */
.five {
    background-image:  url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/12005/starsolid.gif),
                       url(https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/redesign/img/favicon32.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x,
                       repeat-y;
    height: 144px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

es mi primera respuesta ahi va mi opción..

`.imgMulti {
background-image: url("X.png"),url("x.png"), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30, 60, 117, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}`

`<div class="imgMulti"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

yo tenia un problema similar en la seccion *Nos domaines d’activités* de este sitio http://gozlanperez.com/ y lo resolvi con una animación para ir cambiando el background

```
@-webkit-keyframes animation-change-images {

  0%   { background: url('img/animation/1.jpg');}
  33%  {background: url('img/animation/2.jpg');}
  64% { background: url('img/animation/3.jpg');}
  100%   { background: url('img/animation/1.jpg');}
}
@-moz-keyframes animation-change-images {

  0%   { background: url('img/animation/1.jpg');}
  33%  {background: url('img/animation/2.jpg');}
  64% { background: url('img/animation/3.jpg');}
  100%   { background: url('img/animation/1.jpg');}
}
```

y posteriormente aplico la animacion

```
.image-domaines-carousel-1:hover {
  -webkit-animation: animation-change-images 1s infinite;
    animation: animation-change-images 1s infinite;
}
```

es lo que necesitas? saludos